# Limit special characters with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I want my regex to match any string with "special" characters other than `.` and `/`. The other special characters are on a sort of blacklist. However, at runtime, I get an `Illegal repetition` error. How can I resolve that?

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("!@#$%^&*()-_+=|\\}]{[\"':;?><,");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(key);
if (matcher.find()) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it would be better to just specify what is allowed instead of what is denied:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile ("^[\\w\\s\\./]*$");
if (!regex.matcher(key).matches ()) return false;
```

This allows only letters, digits, whitespace, dot ('.') and slash ('/').